# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument-System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'-Error

Tags: powershell

I have a script which needs to run from remote by passing on credentials in the script as as below:-

```
$UserName = Read-Host "Enter User Name:" 
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Your Password:" 
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName , $Password 


Set-Service -Name HiTrust -StartupType Automatic -ComputerName ServerName -credential $Credential 
(Get-Service  -Name "HiTrust" -credential $Credential -ComputerName ServerName).Start() 
Exit
```

However I keep on getting error as below:-

> ```
> Set-Service : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
> At C:\Users\ucub\Desktop\Test.ps1:9 char:15
> + ...             Set-Service -Name HiTrust -StartupType Automatic -Compute ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
> ```

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-5.1), the `-Credentials` parameter was added to the `Set-Service` cmdlet only as of PowerShell version 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on this PSVersion and below, here is your root cause of why this fails on Set-Service...

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

<#
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  503  
#>   



(Get-Command -Name Set-Service).Parameters.Keys
# Results

ComputerName
Name
DisplayName
Description
StartupType
Status
InputObject
PassThru
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
WhatIf
Confirm
```

You have unneeded stuff in the script as well.

I suggest refactoriung to this

```
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-Command).Parameters.Keys
# Results
Session
ComputerName
Credential
...


$ServerName = Read-Host 'Enter a target server name:' 
$ServiceName = Read-Host 'Enter a target service name:' 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {
    "Executing service actions on $env:COMPUTERNAME"
    Set-Service -Name $ServiceName -StartupType Automatic
    Start-Service -Name $ServiceName
} -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that set-service doesn't have a credential parameter. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Service?view=powershell-5.0)

Try something like this:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -Credential $credentials
Set-Service -Name HiTrust -StartupType Automatic
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {Set-Service -Name HiTrust -StartupType Automatic}
```